# How can I pin AutoHotkey to the Window 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, autohotkey

I want to pin a shortcut for AutoHotkey to the Windows 7 taskbar. However, dragging `AutoHotkey.exe` to the taskbar doesn't work as expected.

On my previous computer I was able to pin AutoHotkey to the taskbar without issue. Right clicking the AHK taskbar icon gave me a convenient list of my most recently run scripts. For some reason, this doesn't work on my new laptop.

How can I pin a shortcut to AutoHotkey on the Windows 7 taskbar?

Comment: Right-click the AutoHotkey shortcut in the Start Menu and choose "Pin to taskbar".

Comment: @user3419297 Right-clicking the start menu shortcut doesn't show a "Pin to taskbar" option. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv14S.png))

Comment: In that case, I would re-install AutoHotkey as administrator
after unintalling it.